# Using JavaScript to set an Email Template in Outlook

Tags: outlook

I have JavaScript function, which I use to call Outlook, and it sets the Subject Line, and the Sender. However, I would like to extend this where the user calls Outlook one of the parameters that is passed on via JavaScript to Outlook is the Email Template that the user has selected.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cant do this. Mail clients dont run javascript. Security reasons.

Your code dont use javascript to do this, it only sets subject and sender using a normal link, like `mailto:larry,dan?cc=mike&bcc=sue&subject=test&body=type+your&body=message+here`

Its impossible to set templates, cause this link is default to be used by all the mail clients, and we dont have a default method to set templates in mail clients.